# How to show values in the group column in ag-grid, when group is expanded?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have following data:

```
[{ 'Year': 2016, Month: 'January, 'Other columns...' },
 { 'Year': 2016, Month: 'February, 'Other columns...' }]
```

And I want it to be grouped by year. However, I don't want separate column for Month, when group is expanded, but rather reuse the group column like this:

[image]

I guess `autoGroupColumnDef` is what I need and I achieved almost what I want:

```
gridOptions: GridOptions = {
  suppressAggFuncInHeader: true,
  autoGroupColumnDef: {field: 'Month', headerName: '', cellRendererParams: { suppressCount: true}},
  groupIncludeTotalFooter: true,
};


columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
  {field: 'Year', hide: true, rowGroup: true },
  {field: 'Other Column1', aggFunc: 'sum'},
  {field: 'Other Column2', aggFunc: 'sum'},
];
```

**[see stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-autocolumn-formatting)**

However, the Month values are still aligned right to the year, not under it.

[image]

Comment: Which feature are you using `treedata` or `rowGrouping`? could you provide link to plunk or stackblitz - to play around with it?

Comment: @Paritosh: row grouping. I've created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-autocolumn-formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved easily by CSS.

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-ltr .ag-row-group-leaf-indent {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Have a look at the link: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-autocolumn-formatting-to4fml?file=style.css)